# Xamarin Forms accessing custom p12-file?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Im trying to access file that is in my "Resources"-folder under both iOS- and Android project.

This is how Im trying but failing.

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Merchant_TestCertificate_1234679304.p12");
            bool doesExist = File.Exists(fileName);
```

doesExist is allways false.

Comment: embedded resources are not files and can't be accessed with File IO.  There are numerous existing questions about loading embedded resources in .NET

Comment: @Jason, thank you.